# Does any quantum channel satisfy ${\rm Tr}(\mathcal E^\dagger \mathcal E) \in[0, d^2]$?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-operation, quantum-process-tomography, gate-fidelity

I am reading the paper ["Direct Fidelity Estimation from Few Pauli Measurements"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4695).

According to the paper, the entanglement fidelity between the a unitary channel $\mathcal U$ and a quantum channel $\mathcal E$, is defined as
\begin{align}
F_e = {\rm Tr}[\mathcal U^\dagger \mathcal E]/d^2, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $d$ is dimension of the underlying Hilbert space and ${\rm Tr}(\cdot)$ is the superoperator trace.
My aim is to verify that $F_e \in [-1,1]$. We know that ${\rm Tr}(\mathcal U^\dagger \mathcal U)=d^2$.
After Eq. (41), it is directly provided that for any quantum channel, ${\rm Tr}(\mathcal E^\dagger \mathcal E) \in[0, d^2]$ and ${\rm Tr}(\mathcal U^\dagger \mathcal E) \in[-d^2, d^2]$. How to prove this?

According to Eq. (41), we have
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr}(\mathcal U^\dagger \mathcal E) = \sum_{k=1,k=1}^{d^2, d^2}\chi_{U}(k,k') \chi_{\mathcal E}(k,k'), \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\chi_{\mathcal E}(k,k')=\frac{1}{d}{\rm Tr}(W_k^\dagger \mathcal E(W_{k'}))$ and $W_k$ are Pauli strings. It can be proved that $\chi_{U}(k,k')$ and $\chi_{\mathcal E}(k,k')$ take values in [-1,1] due to Pauli strings. However, following this way, I obtain ${\rm Tr}(\mathcal U^\dagger \mathcal E)\in [-d^4,d^4]$, which is inconsistent with paper.

Comment: Please can you make the question self-contained. What is $\varepsilon$, $U$ and $d$? I also see no quantum channel in the question at the moment.

Comment: What kind of trace is this, if those are channels?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the information.

Comment: What is the "superoperator trace"?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I made some edits such that the question is more in line with the paper. I think this is self-explanatory, no? Traces are defined for linear maps and superoperators are linear maps.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich Ah, I see, those were your edits. Fair enough with the trace (I was more thinking that it would not hurt to be more precise; and in principle, one could also look at trace-like quantities defined on the Choi state, which are not necessarily the trace of the linear map). -- BTW, with the current formulation, I don't quite get why your answer is so long: $\mathrm{tr}(A^\dagger B)$ is a scalar product, and then the result follows from Cauchy-Schwarz. Or should one also prove that $\mathrm{tr}(\mathcal E^\dagger \mathcal E)\le d^2$? (This is also immediate ...

Comment: ... since the eigenvalues of a channel are <=1).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I use the CS argument in the end. However, I think I cannot quite agree with your last conclusion: you would need a bound on the singular values of $\mathcal E$, and these can very well be $> 1$ (for non-unital channels). You can still make this work by restricting to the projection onto diagonal superoperators, but I think that answer will roughly be of the same length. Please let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the bound $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal E^\dagger \mathcal E) \geq 0$ is trivial since $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal E^\dagger \mathcal E) = \| \mathcal E \|_2^2$ is the square of the Schatten 2-norm of $\mathcal E$.

The following is slightly simpler if we use the cyclicity of the trace $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal E^\dagger \mathcal E) = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger)$ and consider the superoperator $\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger$ instead.

To prove the bound $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger) \leq d^2$, note that the trace is the sum of diagonal entries, say in the Pauli basis $W_k$. Thus, we can w.l.o.g. assume that $\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger$ is diagonal in the Pauli basis. Note that any *quantum channel* $\mathcal A$ which is diagonal in the Pauli basis is automatically *unital* (since $\mathcal A^\dagger = \mathcal A$ and $\mathcal A$ is trace-preserving by definition). It is well-known that the spectral norm of unital and trace-preserving quantum channels is $\|\mathcal A\|_\infty = 1$ (see e.g. the book by Watrous, Thm. 4.27).

Now, $\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger$ is *completely positive* but not necessarily trace-preserving (or unital, which is the same as we assumed that $\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger$ is diagonal). This is determined by the first diagonal entry
$$
 \frac1d(\mathbb 1|\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger| \mathbb 1) = \frac1d \|\mathcal E^\dagger(\mathbb 1)\|_2^2.
$$
Here, $\| \cdot \|_2$ is the Schatten 2-norm (or Hilbert-Schmidt / Frobenius norm if you prefer).
Now recall that $\mathcal E$ is trace-preserving and thus $\mathcal E^\dagger$ is unital. Hence, we have
$$
 \frac1d(\mathbb 1|\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger| \mathbb 1) = \frac1d \|\mathcal E^\dagger(\mathbb 1)\|_2^2 = \frac1d \|\mathbb 1\|_2^2 = \frac1d \mathrm{tr}(\mathbb 1) = 1.
$$
Hence, we have shown that $\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger$ is a diagonal quantum channel and thus $\| \mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger \|_\infty = 1$. From this, it immediately follows that
$$
 \| \mathcal E \|_2^2 = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger) \leq d^2 \| \mathcal E \mathcal E^\dagger \|_\infty = d^2.
$$

Finally, we have $\| \mathcal U \|_2^2 = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal U^\dagger \mathcal U) = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{Id}) = d^2$ for any unitary channel $\mathcal U$. Hence, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
 |\mathrm{Tr}(\mathcal U^\dagger \mathcal E)| \leq \| \mathcal U \|_2 \|\mathcal E\|_2 \leq d^2,
$$
for any unitary channel $\mathcal U$ and arbitrary channel $\mathcal E$.