# Proof that $\frac{1}{d} | \text{Tr}(\mathcal{P}_i^\dagger \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j))| \leq 1$ for superoperators

Tags: quantum-operation, pauli-gates

I have two Pauli operators $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \mathcal{P}_i$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \mathcal{P}_j$, and an arbitrary quantum channel $\mathcal{E}$ (in the superoperator/Liouville representation) all acting on a $d=2^n$ dimensional Hilbert space. I want to show that the matrix element $\frac{1}{d} | \text{Tr}(\mathcal{P}_i^\dagger \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j))| \leq 1$.

Is this true? If so, how can one show this? Unfortunately, all inequalities for trace known to me don't work, because neither $\mathcal{P}_i$ or $\mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j)$ are positive semidefinite.

Related question: [Does any quantum channel satisfy ${\rm Tr}(\mathcal E^\dagger \mathcal E) \in[0, d^2]$?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29635/does-any-quantum-channel-satisfy-rm-tr-mathcal-e-dagger-mathcal-e-in0?rq=1) Essentially I am looking for a proof that $\frac{1}{d} | \text{Tr}(\mathcal{P}_k^\dagger \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_{k'}))| = |\chi_\mathcal{E} (k, k')| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It's true. You have a good sense that positive semi-definiteness would help. We don't have it for the Paulis, but we have it for the eigenprojectors.

Let $P_+$ and $P_-$ denote the projectors onto the eigenspaces of $\mathcal{P}_i$ associated with the $+1$ and $-1$ eigenvalues, respectively, and similarly for $R_\pm$ and $\mathcal{P}_j$. Also, set $Q_\pm:=\mathcal{E}(R_\pm)$. Then
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{d}\mathrm{tr}(\mathcal{P}_i^\dagger\mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j)&=\frac{1}{d}\mathrm{tr}((P_+-P_-)^\dagger\mathcal{E}(R_+-R_-))\tag1\\
    &=\frac{1}{d}[\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_+)-\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_+)-\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_-)+\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_-)].\tag2
\end{align}
Now, $P_\pm$ and $R_\pm$ are positive semi-definite. Moreover, $\mathcal{E}$ is completely positive, so $Q_\pm$ are positive semi-definite, too. Hilbert-Schmidt inner product of two positive semi-definite operators is non-negative, so $\mathrm{tr}(P_\pm Q_\pm)\geqslant 0$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
    -\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_+)-\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_+)-\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_-)-\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_-)\tag3\\
    \leqslant\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_+)-\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_+)-\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_-)+\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_-)\tag4\\
    \leqslant\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_+)+\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_+)+\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_-)+\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_-).\tag5
\end{align}
However,
\begin{align}
    &\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_+)+\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_+)+\mathrm{tr}(P_+Q_-)+\mathrm{tr}(P_-Q_-)\tag6\\
    &=\mathrm{tr}((P_++P_-)\mathcal{E}(R_++R_-))\tag7\\
    &=\mathrm{tr}(\mathcal{E}(I))=2^n=d\tag8
\end{align}
where we used the fact that $\mathcal{E}$ is trace preserving. Substituting into the inequalities above and reintroducing normalization constant $\frac{1}{d}$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
    -1\leqslant \frac{1}{d}\mathrm{tr}(\mathcal{P}_i^\dagger\mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j))\leqslant+1\tag9
\end{equation}
as claimed.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the proof and the very cool technique :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-line proof using Hölder's inequality:
$$
|\mathrm{tr}\left( \mathcal{P}_i^\dagger \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_i) \right)| \leq \| \mathcal{P}_i^\dagger \|_\infty \|\mathcal{E}\|_{1\rightarrow1} \| \mathcal{P}_j \|_1 = \| \mathcal{P}_j \|_1 = \mathrm{tr}(I) = d.
$$
We only used that quantum channels have unit $1\rightarrow1$ norm, as well that unitaries have unit spectral norm and trace norm $d$. Note this also works for trace non-increasing CP superoperators (and, more generally, for any superoperator in the $1\rightarrow1$ norm ball, or in the dual $\infty\rightarrow\infty$ ball).

**Note:** $\|\cdot\|_p$ denotes the Schatten $p$-norms, and $\| \cdot \|_{p\rightarrow q}$ is the induced norm on superoperators, i.e.
$$
 \| \Phi \|_{p\rightarrow q} := \sup_{\|X\|_p\leq 1} \|\Phi(X)\|_q \,.
$$

Comment: how's the "$1\to 1$ norm" defined here?

Comment: @glS it is the operator norm induced by the Schatten 1-norm (trace norm) on both domain and image. You can also take the diamond norm if you like (which is the "stabilized" $1\rightarrow 1$ norm).

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, as this is very new to me. $|\text{Tr}(\mathcal{P}_i^\dagger \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j))| = \left\Vert \mathcal{P}_i^\dagger \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j))\right\Vert_1 \leq \left\Vert \mathcal{P}_i^\dagger \right\Vert_\infty \left\Vert\mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j)) \right\Vert_1$ is Hölder's inequality on the Schatten norm. The induced norm (as defined in https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0411077.pdf) is $\left\Vert \mathcal{E} \right\Vert_{q \rightarrow p} = \sup_{X \neq 0} \frac{\left\Vert \mathcal{E}(X) \right\Vert_p}{\left\Vert X \right\Vert_q}$.

Comment: Therefore $\left\Vert\mathcal{E}(\mathcal{P}_j)) \right\Vert_1 \leq \left\Vert \mathcal{E} \right\Vert_{1 \rightarrow 1} \left\Vert \mathcal{P}_j \right\Vert_1$, and we substitute this into the first inequality. Correct?

Comment: @JedBurkat correct, except that the first equality in your first comment is generally an inequality. The operator norm is in general defined for a linear operator between normed spaces, see also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm

Comment: That's all understood. Thank you! :)